# Can Vim apply shiftround to a block as a whole instead of linewise?

Tags: vim

I generally like the shiftround option in Vim, but there are a couple of
situations where it doesn't work very well.  For instance, take this example:

```
f(x,
  y)
```

Selecting the two lines and shifting with `>` and the two lines selected gives
me (and `shiftwidth` set to 4):

```
    f(x,
    y)
```

When I really wanted:

```
    f(x,
      y)
```

In other words, Vim advanced each line of the block to the next tabstop, when I
really wanted it to insert the same amount of inserted on each line--but I want
the least indented line to end up on the next tabstop.

Is there an easy way to get this behavior in Vim?  My goal is to have this work
for `<` and `>` (with a visual selection) rather than other workarounds.

Comment: Yes, I have `expandtab` set.  I typically avoid actual tabs unless I need them.

Comment: What is your softtabstop setting?

Comment: @siu `sts` is set to 4, along with `shiftwidth`.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I'm not sure what you are asking for, but `<<` and `>>` are working as designed.  It's just that I'd like them to behave a little differently. :-)

Comment: Seriously! I can't reproduce the issue. Which version of vim are you using?

Comment: Came here looking for a way to get vim to not f-up c-style multiline comments.  Surely there's a solution to this...?

Comment: @broofa I did come up with something that I'm happy with: https://github.com/jszakmeister/vimuser-jszakmeister/blob/4bc69f1cc601b520c9f50941c4c7daa9849d01bc/vimrc-after.vim#L191 (see the ShiftRound function and the mappings below it)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>, select vertical column before the text you need to shift (<kbd>j</kbd> in your case of just two lines), <kbd>Shift+I</kbd>, insert needed number of tabs or spaces, <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

You can actually use this method to insert arbitrary text, for example you can insert `#` or `//` to comment some code. More info in `:help blockwise-operators`.

Comment: Thank you, but I knew about that already--and use it frequently.  I'm really more interested in making `<<` and `>>` work though.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this via a separate set of mappings that enclose the `>>` commands with a temporary clearing of `'shiftround'`. Here's an implementation:

```
" g>>               Shift [count] lines one 'shiftwidth' rightwards, without
"                   'shiftround'.
"{Visual}[count]>   Shift the highlighted lines [count] 'shiftwidth'
"                   rightwards (for {Visual} see |Visual-mode|), without
"                   'shiftround'.
" g<<, {Visual}[count]<
function! s:Shift( command )
    let s:save_shiftround = &shiftround
    set noshiftround
    return a:command
endfunction
function! s:RestoreShiftRound()
    let &shiftround = s:save_shiftround
    return ''
endfunction
nnoremap <expr> <SID>(RestoreShiftRound) <SID>RestoreShiftRound()
nnoremap <expr> <SID>(ShiftRight) <SID>Shift('>>')
xnoremap <expr> <SID>(ShiftRight) <SID>Shift('>')
nnoremap <expr> <SID>(ShiftLeft) <SID>Shift('<<')
xnoremap <expr> <SID>(ShiftLeft) <SID>Shift('<')
nnoremap <silent> <script> <Plug>(ShiftRightNoRound)          <SID>(ShiftRight)<SID>(RestoreShiftRound)
xnoremap <silent> <script> <Plug>(ShiftRightNoRoundSelection) <SID>(ShiftRight)<SID>(RestoreShiftRound)
nnoremap <silent> <script> <Plug>(ShiftLeftNoRound)           <SID>(ShiftLeft)<SID>(RestoreShiftRound)
xnoremap <silent> <script> <Plug>(ShiftLeftNoRoundSelection)  <SID>(ShiftLeft)<SID>(RestoreShiftRound)
nmap g>> <Plug>(ShiftRightNoRound)
xmap g>  <Plug>(ShiftRightNoRoundSelection)
nmap g<< <Plug>(ShiftLeftNoRound)
xmap g<  <Plug>(ShiftLeftNoRoundSelection)
```

I didn't cover the `>{motion}` command, as that would be more complex.

Comment: Wouldn't that skip stopping at the correct tab stop though?  What I really want is it to look at the least indented line in my selected block, compute the amount of space to add to reach the next tab stop for that line, and then shift the entire block by that same amount of space.  I guess I'm going to have to write something to do it.  I was really hoping I was just missing something that did it already.

Comment: Yes, this assumes that the basic structure (the `f(` in your example) is correctly indented, and only the arguments are off. For what you want, you'd have to write a more complex function.